# Divisibility relation on the set of monomials of degree $n$ minimal elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $n\ge 1$ be an integer and $\operatorname{Mon}(n)=\{X_1^{i_1}X_2^{i_2}...X_n^{i_n}|i_1, i_2, ..., i_n \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\}$. On $\operatorname{Mon}(n)$ we consider the partial order given by divisibility i.e. $$X_1^{i_1}X_2^{i_2}...X_n^{i_n}\le X_1^{j_1}X_2^{j_2}...X_n^{j_n}\iff i_1\le j_1, i_2\le j_2,..., i_n\le j_n.$$
Prove that with respect to this partial order any nonempty subset of $\operatorname{Mon}(n)$ has a finite number of minimal elements.

Here are my thoughts on this. It is clear that we are only interested in considering infinite subsets of $\operatorname{Mon}(n)$. I thought that, given such a subset, we may be able to show that any chain has a lower bound, so by Zorn's Lemma we would get that such a minimal element always exists (I think that the fact that any chain has a lower bound should somehow follow from the fact that any subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a minimum, but I don't know how to formalize this/whether it is actually true). However, I don't see how this would help me to show that there can only be finitely many such minimal elements.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_lemma

Comment: @user26857 thank you, I wasn't aware that this is in fact some theorem.